# error class conexion con base de datos MYSQL y PHP

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, phpmyadmin, mysqlconnector

Hola a todos estoy teniendo problemas con una clase de conexion con mi base de datos Mysql

este es el error

**Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysqli_connect_connect() in C:\xampp\htdocs\casa moa\altas\class\conexion.php:22 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\casa moa\altas\class\conexion.php(33): ConexionBD->conectar() #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\casa moa\altas\class\productos.php(47): ConexionBD->ejecutarsentencia('select * from c...') #2 C:\xampp\htdocs\casa moa\altas\listados.php(4): Producto->Listar() #3 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\casa moa\altas\class\conexion.php on line 22**

por lo que he visto es por la versión obsoleta pero ya actualice y aun así me marca error

esta es mi clase

```
<?php
class ConexionBD    
{
    
    var $servidor;
    var $base_datos;
    var $usuario;
    var $password;
    var $conexion;
    
    
    function ConexionBD()
    {
        $this->base_datos="moa";
        $this->servidor="localhost";
        $this->usuario="";
        $this->password="";
    }
    
    function conectar()
    {
        $this->conexion=mysqli_connect($this->servidor,$this->usuario,$this->password);
        mysqli_select_db($this->base_datos,$this->conexion);
    }
    
    function desconectar()
    {
        mysqli_close($this->conexion);
    }
    
    function ejecutarsentencia($sql)
    {
    $this->conectar();
    $resultados=mysqli_query($sql,$this->conexion);
    
    if(preg_match("/insert/i", $sql))
    $resultados = mysqli_insert_id($this->conexion);
    
    $this->desconectar();
    return $resultados;
    
    }
}
```

?>

Comment: no sobra un connect?

Comment: si, jajaja pero aun asi tengo el error

Comment: y ahora que error da??? porque no es el mismo si ya cambiaste y arreglaste ese

Comment: Si ya corregiste el mysqli_connect_connect y te sigue tirando error, 
probá de poner var_dump(mysqli_connect_error()); después del connect y escribí el resultado acá.

Comment: Warning: mysqli_select_db() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, string given in C:\xampp\htdocs\casa moa\altas\class\conexion.php on line 23

Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, string given in C:\xampp\htdocs\casa moa\altas\class\conexion.php on line 34

Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, null given in C:\xampp\htdocs\casa moa\altas\class\productos.php on line 50

Warning: mysqli_free_result() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, null given in C:\xampp\htdocs\casa moa\altas\class\productos.php on line 70

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, tenés varios problemas:

1. Si usás mysqli_select_db como función, y no como clase, recibe 2 parámetros: mysqli_select_db(mysqli $link , string $dbname);
   En este caso, deberías pasarle $this->conexion como primer parámetro. Entonces te quedaría así:

   mysqli_select_db($this->conexion,$this->base_de_datos);
2. Mismo que lo anterior con el mysqli_query. Primero pasale $this-conexion, y después $sql

   mysqli_query($this->conexion, $sql)
3. No estás validando nada. Esa clase deja de funcionar si no tenés conexión a la base de datos. Te va a tirar errores. Lo ideal sería que valides siempre. Usá try {} catch (e), o con simples if, y validá que todo funcione.
4. Si vas a hacer una conexión a la base de datos como clase, te recomiendo que la hagas singleton. Es importante que la clase de conexión se ejecute una sola vez, para no estar conectando y desconectando cada vez que tenés que hacer un query.
   Para eso, lo ideal es hacerla Singleton (es un patrón bastante sencillo, que sirve para que solamente se pueda tener una instancia en todo el código de esa clase), y poner que la conexión se haga en el constructor, como lo estás haciendo. De esa forma, te asegurás que la conexión se haga una sola vez, y no cada vez que hagas un "new ConexionDB"

Answer (score 0):

ya esta, estaba poniendo mal la estructura mysqli_select_db($this->base_datos,$this->conexion); la cambie por mysqli_select_db($this->conexion,$this->base_datos); muchas gracias